# trying to check file size and delete it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code where i am trying to check the file size and if its under 15GB, i am allowing them to upload,

My issue is happening when i upload no file, i get an error

**size is undefined**

```
$(document).on('change', '#fileUpload', function(e) {
            let size = (typeof this.files[0].size !== "undefined") ? this.files[0].size : '';
            if(size != '') {
                if(size > '15728640') {
                        Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: 'Oops...',
                        text: "File is Too big to Upload. Maximum file size allowed is 15MB"
                    });
                    document.getElementById('SubmitButton_ID').disabled=true;
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('SubmitButton_ID').disabled=false;
                }
            } else {
                document.getElementById('SubmitButton_ID').disabled=false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "upload no file"?

Comment: like first i selected a file, it worked, then i cliked the upload and choose no file and on the change event, t it fired, because it has no size, it throw an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when you do not have a file selected you get an error? So check to see if you have a file before running the check.

```
const submitButton = document.getElementById('SubmitButton_ID');
const hasFiles = !!this.files.length;
if (!hasFiles) {
  submitButton.disabled = true;
  return;
}
```